# DOS rename files with mask

Tags: dos, rename

Old school problem in DOS...

I have a bunch of files

- Canada ABCD.txt
- USA ABCD.txt

etc

I need to replace **ABCD** with **Ridvan**.

Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ren *ABCD.txt *Ridvan.txt
```

I've just tested this and it works for me. If it doesn't work for you, you'll need to give more info about your specific file names.